# segmentation fault - file writing

Tags: c, file-io, gdb

I am getting a segmentation fault while writing to file parent2.txt represented by the variable fp2. I put comments at the line where the program stopped running and at the line responsible for the issue. I am guessing the segmentation fault is a result of "temp4.value" being set to null, even though I thought I gave it a value. There seems to be an issue with the line, "temp2 = *temp2.next". temp2 is a variable of the child struct. I don't know what exactly is wrong with the code, which is what I need help with. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Parent
{
    char *value;
    struct Child *next;
    int numChildren;
}Parent;

typedef struct Child
{
    char *value;
    struct Child *next;
    Parent *prev1;
    struct Child *prev2;
}Child;

int isFirst(int parent[], int index)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        if (parent[i] == parent[index])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int addChild(Parent parents[], int index, char *num)
{
    int i;
    Child temp, temp2;
    temp.value = num;
    if (parents[index].numChildren == 0)
    {
        parents[index].next = &temp;
        temp.prev1 = &parents[index];
        temp.prev2 = NULL;
    }
    else
    { 
        for (i = 0; i < parents[index].numChildren; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                temp2 = *parents[index].next;
            }
            else
            {
                temp2 = *temp2.next; // setting temp2 to null?
            }
        }
        temp.prev1 = NULL;
        temp.prev2 = &temp2;
        temp2.next = &temp;
    }
}

int main() { 

    FILE *fp, *fp2;
    char read_file [256];
    char current[256];
    char space = ' ';
    char *curr2, *curr3;
    int i, index;
    int j = 0;
    int parent[] = {1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1};
    int child[] = {3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 100};
    Parent parents[10];
    Parent temp;
    Child temp2, temp3;
    int numParents = 0;
    int done = 0;

    fp = fopen ("/home/sam/parent.txt","w+");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf ("Error opening file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }




    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%d", parent[i]);
        fprintf(fp, " ");
        fprintf(fp, "%d", child[i]);
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        fgets(current, 7, fp);
        printf("%s\n", current);
        curr2 = strtok(current, &space);
        if (isFirst(parent, i) == 1)
        {
            parents[numParents].value = curr2;
            parents[numParents].numChildren = 0;
            numParents++;
        }
        printf("%s\n", curr2);
        curr3 = strtok(NULL, &space);
        while (done == 0)
        {
            temp = parents[j];
            index = j;
            if (temp.value == curr2)
            {
                done = 1;
            }
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        printf("\n");
        addChild(parents, numParents-1, curr3);
        parents[index].numChildren++;
        printf("%s\n", curr3);
        done = 0;
    }

    fp2 = fopen ("/home/sam/parent2.txt","w+");

    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        printf ("Error opening file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    Child temp4;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp2, "%s", parents[i].value);
        temp4 = *parents[i].next;
        for (j = 0; j < parents[i].numChildren; j++)
        {
            fprintf(fp2, "%s", temp4.value); // segmentation fault occuring on this line second time through inner loop
            fprintf(fp2, " ");
            if (j < parents[i].numChildren-1)
            {
                temp4 = *temp4.next;
            }
        }
        fprintf(fp2, "\n");
    }
    rewind(fp2);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        fgets(current, 100, fp2);
        printf("%s\n", current);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run it under a debugger!

Comment: after using gdb on the linux terminal, i got the message: "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00007ffff7aa5b91 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6". Do you know what this means?

Comment: Most likely it means you didn't compile with `-g` and you don't know how to use the `where` command. :)

Comment: I did use "-g", but I don't really know how to use gdb, so no, I don't know how to use the where command.

Comment: Ok, I edited my blurb at the beginning, and I just need an explanation as to what's wrong with a certain 2 lines of code

Comment: Sorry, have to downvote this for lack of research effort...  google "gdb cheatsheet", "how to use gdb", "use debugger to find segfault", etc. and the answer will lie before you.

Comment: I did, and I discovered where the segfault is occurring, and what line is messing everything up, I just want to know how to fix the problem.

Comment: Ok.  If you're really lucky, someone will work through your code and find this.  In the meantime there are other things with a debugger you can learn how to do.  Determine which value is being improperly read from or written to on the line that is segfaulting.  And when posting to SO (or any sort of group or list serv) it's best practice to shorten your code as much as you possibly can while still leaving the error happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problems starts already up here, in the `addChild` function

```
int addChild(Parent parents[], int index, char *num)
{
    int i;
    Child temp, temp2;
    temp.value = num;
    if (parents[index].numChildren == 0)
    {
        parents[index].next = &temp;     // <---
        temp.prev1 = &parents[index];
        temp.prev2 = NULL;
    }
```

You assign the address of a local variable to a member of the `Parent` structure. When the function returns, this will point to an object that has disappeared (a dangling pointer).

Any use of that pointer later will cause all kinds of trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would the solution be to pass a pointer to a parent as a parameter?

Comment: Probably not (I'm not exactly sure what you want to do). The usual way to get objects that outlive the function is to allocate space for them with `malloc`.

Comment: Well the objective is to have a linked list for each number in the parent array. As indexes 0-2 and 7 in the parent array equal one, a parent object would point to child[0], which would point to child[1], to child[2], to child[7]. I am then trying to write this to a file using pointers. But, thank you again, for your help

Comment: @Sam You're dynamically constructing a data structure so malloc is certainly the way to go.